# Changing column from longtext to mediumtext taking over 1 hour

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, longtext

I am storing html in my database as text, and initially I used longtext because I just assumed it was what I needed. I queried my html and urls from my database using the full text and it took a long time and memory so I thought it was the large amount of html I was querying and decided to change longtext to mediumtext to make it faster, I have about 40,000 rows so I needed to change it before it gets higher. After running the query it's taking a long time and it's been over 1 and 1/2 hours. Is this usually how much time it takes or did I probably mess up somewhere?

Comment: Of course you tested this on a different MySQL Instance on a backup of your database right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ALTER` must copy the entire table over and rebuild all(?) the indexes.  That is what is taking "a long time".

Essentially the only differences between `LONGTEXT` and `MEDIUMTEXT` are

- One extra byte per row for the 'length' for that column.
- The limit for storing the data -- That is, a 17MB string will be chopped at 16KB when stored into `MEDIUMTEXT`.

Neither of those impact memory allocation or disk allocation (other than the 1 byte) or speed of anything.  In both cases, your HTML is stored as a 3- or 4-byte length followed by as much or as little HTML as you give it.

If you are having performance problems, please provide a slow query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.